# как с помощью цикла посчитать одну и ту же сортировку по времени несколько раз

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте как с помощью библиотеки хроно посчитать время сортировки несколько раз одного и того же масива (тоже самое что я просто запущу пограмму несколько раз только это сделать через цикл)

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    A[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;

}
auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
sort2(A, N);
auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
int elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds> (end - begin).count();
cout << elapsed << "нс   ";
```

Comment: Вот в этом ответе есть то, что Вам надо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056524/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-list-%d0%b8-forward-list/1056547?noredirect=1#comment1806840_1056547.  Там пример кода - подергайте от туда то, что Вам нужно

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как с помощью библиотеки Хроно сделать так чтобы время было в секундах а не в нано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1057074/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%a5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: Кроме организации копии исходных данных ничего в голову не приходит. Только учтите, время сортировки после копирования будет не совсем честное (условия доступа к данным уже не те, что в "боевой программе")

Comment: Если позволяют объемы памяти, то сначала создай M штук копий массива, а потом под таймером замеряй только их сортировку, тогда ты минимизируешь сайд эффекты.